# How to show index creation time with _cat/indices API in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 5.2, and cannot see `index creation time` with `http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v`.

Just wonder what options will show `index creation time` for each of the indices.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Have a look at the [cat API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat.html) : you can get the list of available parameters via `http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?help`

To get the creation date of your indexes, you would use `creation.date` (or `creation.date.string`). For example, use

```
http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?h=h,s,i,id,p,r,dc,dd,ss,creation.date.string
```

For full header names:

```
http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?h=health,status,index,id,pri,rep,docs.count,docs.deleted,store.size,creation.date.string&v=
```

Comment: How can I sort the indexes by creation date?

Comment: @VedranMaricevic For ES5, append  `&s=creation.date`, something like `http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?h=h,s,i,id,p,r,dc,dd,ss,creation.date.string&s=creation.date`

Comment: thanks for including the "help" endpoint. and the documentation that documents the help endpoint! if you just go to the cat indices API then there is no reference to a "help".

Comment: how to get this through python client?
i tried below, getting lots of information

`es.indices.get('*')` if I give search index directly, not getting createddate `es.indices.get('index_name')`. thanks.

Comment: @anandbabu You should use `es.cat.indices`, not `es.indices.get`. In the python client, use keyword params "h" for headings and "s" for sort key. Like this: `print(es.cat.indices("index_name", h=("h","s","i","id","p","r","dc","dd","ss","creation.date.string"), s="creation.date"))`. The same also works with no index name, or "*".

Comment: Official ES and useful examples: [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html) and [here - old version](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/cat-indices.html)

Comment: `?help` is really useful! thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Update 2024-01, ES v 8.11.

The page on [cat indices API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html) doesn't explain this but says "apps should use the [get index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-index.html)". Which also doesn't explain it.

The recipe in nikoshr's answer (using the `_cat` endpoint) still works... but unfortunately you get a plain text Response, not JSON.

I got [an answer](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/where-if-anywhere-does-es-documentation-explain-about-metadata-specifically-index-creation-datetimes/350185/2?u=mrodent) from the ES forum (the answerer there says that it's not properly documented):

```
url = f'{ES_URL}/_settings?human&filter_path=*.settings.index.creation_date_string'
```

... this will indeed return a JSON-bearing Response containing all the indices on your server. Note the glob: you can filter on parts of index names if you want.